# GAE/J after upgrade to 1.9.3 can not retrieve child records in one to many relationships

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to upgrade my app from GAE 1.8.1 to 1.9.3, apparently there is one major issue with retrieving child records in any one to many relationship I have.

In the old version I was using datanucleus JDO version 1 and everything worked fine. Now I am using version 2.

After the upgrade I can only retrieve parent objects (the child are nulls), although when I create new data it seems to be working fine.

I checked how the new data looks like in the database viewer, and it seems that the one-to-many column in the class of the old data is labeled as "missing".

If I create new data the data is filled with some index information.

I will appreciate any help

**Update**
Apparently datanucleus JDO version 2 is not fully backward compatible to version 1. If you're going to consider an upgrade verified the data relationships were not broken (like mine did)

My current solution is to stay with version 1 and use the newest GAE SDK (which seems to be working well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently datanucleus JDO version 2 is not fully backward compatible to version 1. If you're going to consider an upgrade verified the data relationships were not broken (like mine did)

My current solution is to stay with version 1 and use the newest GAE SDK (which seems to be working well)